# Opening Content in New Frame not Working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using Javascript to open a page in a different frame using onclick. I had this working when last tested, but was made aware yesterday that it no longer works in Chrome. I retested the other browsers and its still working as expected. I know Chrome can be a little finicky when it comes to Javascript, I'm just not sure how to resolved.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="downloadReport" runat="server">
     <img  src="images/save.jpg" onclick="javascript:top.frames['main'].location = 'DownloadReport.aspx?<%= url %>';return true;" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

What do I need to do to resolve the issue in Chrome? And please refrain from a discussion on why frames are or aren't a good idea. While in most cases things can be accomplished in different ways, there are some specific uses for them still.

Comment: Two questions: 1) What does the rendered output actually look like in the page - can you post that? 2) Do you see any errors in the Chrome console log?

Comment: @JamesThorpe There is no output because clicking on the image no longer seems to have any effect. The console log also shows nothing. All other browsers still function correctly.

Comment: I mean the rendered HTML output that's actually the source of the page that Chrome sees - ie not the aspx you've posted above that's run on the server

Comment: I would try putting an absolute URL into the pathname as well       http://www.website.com/path/DownloadReport.aspx?<%= url %>', to see if that might be the issue.

Comment: @JamesThorpe since this is run at server, it doesn't show that code in the way that I believe you are asking for by showing "view source".

Comment: @med116 The URL is dynamically generated from backend C# code so in production I wouldn't be able to hard code it. For testing purposes though I did as you asked and there is no change to functionality.

Comment: Yes - I did mean to view the source to show what's actually sent to the browser, since that's the bit that'll actually affect what's going on in Chrome

Comment: @JamesThorpe Since its run at the server, then the detailed code wouldn't show as you are requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I was thinking that Chrome needed to access frames by `id` where as others could use `name` or `id`, that was apparently incorrect. Chrome required the frame `name`. So on my frameset page I added a name attribute in addition to the id one and everything is working again as needed.

```
<frameset rows="100,*" border="0">
   <frame name="top" id="top" runat="server" />
   <frame name="main" id="main" runat="server" />
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use hyperlink in this scenario, prevent its default behavior by doing `return false;` instead of `return true;`

But if you don't need it - just use the image without hyperlink (adding styling for cursor if needed):

```
<img  src="images/save.jpg" onclick="top.frames['main'].location = 'DownloadReport.aspx?<%= url %>'" style="cursor:pointer" />
```

Comment: Tried both of the above and still no change.

Comment: What about using `top.frames['main'].location.href` instead of just `top.frames['main'].location` ?

Comment: Tried the above comment and still no change.